redirect public ip on https to domain nginx
I am using nginx
i have a domain configured on https example https://mywebsite.com
when if i am trying to put its public ip on browser example https://10.1.2.1 it gives message connection not secure.
I want to write an configuration nginx where if user put https://10.1.2.1 on browser it always automatically redirect it domain https://mywebsite.com
how to achieve this?
